Create a concave shape from a circle SVG
I need to create a concave shape from this painted circle that looks like a saucer.


Hello do you mean that each shape is supposed to be hollow, or to be a hole?

hello there thank you for ur comment and yes i want it ti be hollow lets say like a dish or a pendent

Import your image as Image > Reference then convert Trace Image to Grease Pencil (note that the new object will be overlapping the image so you need to move the image to see it):

Now convert this object to bezier curve (again, move the former object in order to see the new):

Convert the bezier object to mesh:

Clean the object (remove the double stroke and the circle):

Create a filled circle object, put it behind the pattern object, switch it to Edit mode, CtrlLMB to select the pattern object and use the Knife Project tool:

Result (X > Delete Faces to get holes):


it worked thank you, still have a problem in concave it like a dish or half sphere

what do you mean? Please edit your original question and show a screenshot

Follow moonboots' instructions to create mesh, turn on proportional editing at the top of the screen, switch the mode to "sphere", select the center vertex or vertices (you may have to subdivide to get more vertices, right click and select subdivide), and drag the vertex/vertices down with the 'G' key to create a concave shape.
